# Incompatible ranks 0 and 2 in assignment at (1)

Tags: arrays, fortran, gfortran

I cannot get my head around arrays and scalars in gfortran. So when trying to run these three equations

```
REAL(8), DIMENSION(1:NI, 1:NJ) :: Slope_rad, Aspect_rad

REAL(8) :: clearsky,theta,theta_PyrStat, &
    Transmissivity,I0,Pressure

REAL(8), DIMENSION(runl) :: SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad, &
                       SolarAzimuthAngle_rad, rm_r2, PRESS_in, Hillshade, P

theta = acos(cos(Slope_rad)) *cos(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T)) & 
            +sin(Slope_rad)*sin(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T)) & 
            *cos(SolarAzimuthAngle_rad(T)-Aspect_rad)           

clearsky = I0*rm_r2(T)*Transmissivity**(P/(Press_IN(T)*cos(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T))))*cos(theta);

Hillshade(T) = 255*((cos(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T))*cos(Slope_rad)) &
            +(sin(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T)) * sin(Slope_rad)) &
            *cos(SolarAzimuthAngle_rad(T) - Aspect_rad))
```

I'm getting the following errors

```
main.f90:406:3:

theta = acos(cos(Slope_rad)) *cos(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T)) &
```

1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 2 in assignment at (1)
main.f90:411:3:

```
clearsky = I0*rm_r2(T)*Transmissivity**(P/(Press_IN(T)*cos(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T))))*cos(theta);
```

1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 1 in assignment at (1)
main.f90:417:3:

```
Hillshade(T) = 255*((cos(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T))*cos(Slope_rad)) &
```

1
Error: Incompatible ranks 0 and 2 in assignment at (1)

Comment: You should show the drfinition of your arrays and variables (see [mcve]). Please use tag [tag:fortran] forvall Fortran questions. Add a version tag when the question is version specific (this one is not).

Comment: One of the variables on the right side is an array, probably `Slope_rad`, but without the declarations it is hard to say which one. I am sure it is a duplocatebof some other question but I cannot close it because I had tu put there the fortran tag myself.

Comment: `cos(Slope_rad)` - `Slope_rad` is a 2D (rank 2) array and the `cos` function expects a scalar (rank 0) argument. You need to specify which index of `Slope_rad` to use. E.g. `cos(Slope_rad(1,1))`

Comment: Similarly, `P` is a rank 1 array, you need to specify which index to use here `...Transmissivity**(P/...`.

Comment: @SteveES That is not entirely correct. `cos()` does not have any problem accepting an array, it is an elemental function. The error happens later.

Comment: @VladimirF Good point, but in their situation (where the left-hand side is a scalar and they aren't aggregating anything on the right-hand side) the cos() function argument should be a scalar. I guess technically the error is because they are trying to do `scalar = array * scalar`, which won't work?

Comment: I'm also not sure why `acos(cos(Slope_rad))` is necessary, surely this is just `Slope_rad`?

Comment: That is probably a typo in parenthesis.

Comment: Thanks all - SteveES got it - now sorted. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your `Slope_rad` is an array. Therefore `cos(Slope_rad)` is still an array. You cannot assign an array into a scalar `theta`.

First decide what `Slope_rad` means, if it should be an array or a scalar, what the value means and then study what

```
theta = acos(cos(Slope_rad)) *cos(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T)) & 
            +sin(Slope_rad)*sin(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T)) & 
            *cos(SolarAzimuthAngle_rad(T)-Aspect_rad)
```

should mean.

As SteveES noted, `acos(cos(Slope_rad))` is a strange thing to use anyway, whatever `Slope_rad` is.

Answer (score 0):

Let's pick this apart by looking at the rank of each variable, working back from the assignment of `theta`:

```
Rank(2, (1:NI, 1:NJ)) :: Slope_rad, Aspect_rad

Rank(0) :: clearsky, theta, theta_PyrStat, Transmissivity, I0,Pressure

Rank(1, (runl)) :: SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad, SolarAzimuthAngle_rad, &
                   rm_r2, PRESS_in, Hillshade, P
```

Note that here I've invented a notation for rank - `Rank(N [, (D1, D2, ..., D<N>)])` where `N` is the array rank (0 for scalars) and `(D1, D2, ..., D<N>)` is an optional list of dimensions (empty for scalars).

So looking at `theta` (adjusted based on Vladimir F's comment) and assuming `T` is an array index (vs a function argument):

```
theta = acos(cos(Slope_rad) * cos(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T))   & 
             + sin(Slope_rad) * sin(SolarZenithAngleCorr_rad(T)) & 
             * cos(SolarAzimuthAngle_rad(T) - Aspect_rad))
```

we should see a 'conservation of rank' if we focus on the shape of each variable and function:

```
Rank(0) =? acos(cos(Rank(2)) * cos(Rank(1))        & 
              + sin(Rank(2)) * sin(Rank(1))        & 
              * cos(Rank(1) - Rank(2)))
```

Mathematical functions like `sin`, `cos`, and `acos` are *elemental* (the function is performed on each element of the array) and return values take the shape of the arguments provided, so, for example, `sin(Rank(2)) = Rank(2)`. A problem arises when you try to calculate `cos(SolarAzimuthAngle_rad(T) - Aspect_rad)` because `SolarAzimuthAngle_rad(T) - Aspect_rad = Rank(1) - Rank(2)` which throws an inconsistent rank error.

It may be helpful to first write these expressions using loops and manually perform the per-element operations, then verify the code is working as desired, and finally refactor it into a more compact array operation form.